# Eagle: Remove some text of a component label

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, footprint

I routed a small board that will get connected to a BeagleBone Black using two 8x2 pin header connectors.

As you can see on the picture there's two labels that are drawn out of the board layout so when I upload the board on OshPark the board is bigger that what it should be.

How can I remove those two circled labels without editing the eagle component library?

Do I have to generate my own gerber files and don't use the OshPark's website to generate them?

I'm new to eagle.

[image]

Comment: You will have to edit the component and remove the text.

Comment: I'm not familiar with eagle, but can't you define a mechanical outline for your board? The implication being that anything outside this should be ignored.

Comment: @brhans Even though you claim to be not familiar with Eagle you gave IMO the correct answer: what is outside the board borader will be ignored by all boardhouses I have used. Hence A.G. Does not need to do anything at all.

Comment: So no problems ! I will edit the part to change the Pin 1 shape as suggested bitmask. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to edit the part.  Don't be intimidated!  Eagle parts are fairly straightforward, and you have the benefit of an already-built part to modify.

I've gotten to the point that I don't even use the libraries that come with Eagle.  It takes me longer to verify the library part than to create my own :)

If you do edit the part to remove the silkscreen labels, I suggest making Pin 1 a square shape.  This way you'll have some way of figuring out the orientation on the board itself.  Once you're done, you'll need to click `Library -> Update` in your design.

Another option is to make the Gerbers, but even then you would need a gerber editor to remove the unwanted silkscreen...

Good luck!

Comment: I will edit the part at least to make Pin 1 a square shape, that's a very good tip. I change the connector to another which only display name and value so I can smash it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to SMASH the part, select the label, and try to delete it.  Not sure if smash has that functionality, but I think it does.

Comment: Smash only works for name and value, the only way I can think of is to edit the component and remove the text.

Comment: Smash does not work for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about OSH park or any other fab houses, whatever is outside of the board will get ignored. You can use SMASH tool in Eagle, but it only works on some labels like >NAME and >VALUE, it doesn't work general labels. When I design a connector, instead of using 1 for pin I use >VALUE and then use 1 as a value when I place the component on the board, then I can SMASH it and move the 1 where I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the error by going to: "Settings> Misc" and deselect "display via lengths", "display pad names" and "display signal names".